# Should shortcuts, brevity, and cleverness be routinely skipped in favor of clarity?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

This question came to mind after seeing this simple piece of code:

```
if (!x%y)
{
    // do something
}
```

Maybe it's the influence of early C books (K&R?), but isn't the following always preferred, if not as cute?

```
if (x%y != 0)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Absolutely, just be careful you get the logic right, as your first example is not equivalent to your second example.

Comment: yeah, watch out for order-of-operations.

Comment: It makes no difference to the compiler and the generated code will be absolutely identical. Therefore you should write your source to be as clear to humans as possible.

Comment: @Martin: It *does* make a difference, because `!x%y` is parsed as `(!x)%y` :)

Comment: This sort of subjective discussion belongs on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is one of those questions that just *barely* teeters on the threshold of subjectivity.  There are solid, objective reasons to prefer the second expression over the first - as inadvertently demonstrated by the OP: namely, the first is easier to silently screw up.  And I think from a maintenance perspective, the answer is pretty clear.

Comment: Somehow I have this slight suspicion that the whole point of this question was to troll in favor of hideous `!= 0` constructs by tricking the people who hate them into thinking that `!x%y` is the same as `!(x%y)` and looking like fools. ;-)

Comment: @ FredOverflow: When talking about one version over another you have to assume that both have the same meaning otherwise the discussion is moot. The fact the OP actually got the translation wrong is just another argument for clarity over cleverness. So I win either way :-)

Comment: Zero is false (x%y) => x%y !=0 ; !(x%y) => x%y == 0 Why everybody write "!= 0"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This quote](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2003/10/08/sig_quote_of_the_day/) answers your question.

> "Debugging is twice as hard as writing
>   the code in the first place.
>   Therefore, if you write the code as
>   cleverly as possible, you are, by
>   definition, not smart enough to debug
>   it." – Brian W. Kernighan

Comment: No it doesn't. The OP isn't talking about coding "as cleverly as possible", rather, he's talking about this specific case of use of `!` versus `!= 0`.  (Also, would it have been too difficult to actually put the quote here?)

Comment: I think (due to the title) that the OP is talking about cleverness versus brevity in general, and using the modulo expression as an example.

Comment: @Billy -- I think it does.  Reading the question itself, it's clear that he's talking about being clever in general.  The body of the post is just a specific example.  Though I agree that he should just put the quote here, fixed.

Comment: Others answered similarly, and some even said that two code snipers are not the same (which is true). I mostly agree with Konerak. btw thanks PigBen.

Comment: +1 for answering with a K&R quote, because in my view this is a direct result of K&R's C book.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure about that code? `!x%y` means `(!x)%y` because `!`binds tighter than `%`.

(For that reason alone, I would prefer `x % y != 0`.)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, props to everyone noticing that `(!x%y)` is not equivalent to `(!(x%y))`, but more importantly, neither of them is equivalent to:

```
if (x % y != 0)
```

which has a much nicer form:

```
if (x % y)
```

Personally I try not to write `==0` when it can be replaced by use of `!` without introducing excessive parentheses, and I absolutely never use `!=0`, but this is a discussion that will start flamewars. :-)

Comment: This. The zero is false, everything else true semantic is *deeply* embedded in c derived language and *is* extremely clear, but loose `!`'s take parsing.

Comment: I sometimes use "!!" as a pseudo-operator to convert non-zero and zero to the values 1 and 0, respectively.  I use "!!" sometimes in places where it isn't necessary, to emphasize that a numerical expression may return something other than 0 or 1, but non-zero values will be mapped to 1.  I also use it when e.g. I want a function that returns an 'int' to return non-zero if a value of type 'long' is non-zero (without the "!!", the "int" might return zero even if the long was non-zero; actually, if the return type is signed, it might even trigger nasal demons).

Comment: @supercat: Yes, I do that too. People who are happy not supporting pre-C99 compilers might just write `(bool)` though.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer clarity over brevity.  The second example `x % y != 0` is more clear.

Of course, what constitutes clarity is somewhat subjective, but I prefer to reserve the unary `!` operator for boolean variables or functions returning boolean.

The way I usually try to gauge clarity as I write code is by asking myself: would I easily be able to read and understand this line if 1) someone else wrote it or 2) I had to read it again 2 years down the line.

Answer (score 2):

Cleverness should be skipped. It isn't clever... or more importantly maintainable.

Shortcuts and brevity may or may not be acceptable: we all take shortcuts but there are almost "industry standard" shortcuts because we all do it. No clever shortcuts though

Answer (score 1):

Clarity wins over brevity every day, in my opinion.  I sometimes feel that writing code such as:

```
if(!(x = func(y)) && ++z == x)
```

...is the equivalent to go-faster stripes on a car.  It may feel fast, but it isn't.  I also don't think that using incomprehensible variable names (such as in the above example) to save on typing is a good idea.

What is better here:

```
for(int x(0) x < managers.size(); ++x)
    managers[x]->initialise();
```

or:

```
for(int mgr(0); mgr < managers.size(); ++mgr)
    managers[mgr]->initialise();
```

They both accomplish the same thing and one could argue that there's no point making `mgr` more clear (there's even other arguments to say `mgr` should be *clearer* :) ).  But if ever this part of the routine gets more complicated, it might be very important:

```
for(int mgr(0); mgr < managers.size(); ++mgr)
{
    for(int dependentMgr(0); dependentMgr < managers[mgr].dependents().size(); ++dependentMgr)
    {
        // init these first
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is not a discussion on whether to use iterators or not, merely whether we should use clear names or not.

When I look at a piece of code I have not seen before, the variable names are everything.  I cringe when I see `tmp` and `tempt2` and `vec2`.  They mean nothing.

Seriously people, if you're worrying about the amount you're typing, get an IDE with autocomplete or go raise chickens in Fiji :)

Comment: +1 go-faster stripes. Reminds me of the Simpsons' "speed holes" when Homer was getting shot.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you want your code to be self-documenting (Martin Fowler Style), you can use the more verbose:

```
every_player_gets_equal_points = x%y;
if (!every_player_gets_equal_points) { //Some players get more: now base on completion time
```

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet you present, ...

```
if (!x%y)
{
    // do something
}
```

... is meaningless and therefore most likely incorrect, since `!x%y` is equivalent to `!x` except for the cases of `y` equals -1, 0, or 1, and in the `y` equals 0 case it's Undefined Behavior (i.e., `%y` is generally meaningless).

Others have already remarked that the first snippet is not equivalent to the second more verbose one. But then one could wonder which snippet expresses the intention. My point is that the first snippet is not equivalent to anything that is likely to be correct.

And so this illustrates nicely that clarity is a good idea.

Cheers & hth.,